# The Stored Procedure return NULL instead of 0

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a question - When I try to execute this SELECT statement I do not receive anything. I want to receive 0 values for the two columns. When I tried with ISNULL() or COALESCE() but nothing is happened.Here is the SELECT Statement:

```
SELECT 
    ACI.codinv AS codinv
    , ISNULL(COUNT(distinct ACI.appln_id), 0) AS CountInd
From    
    i_applnid_codinv aci 
    Inner Join i_applndata d On aci.appln_id = d.appln_id 
    Inner Join
        (Select x.appln_id, Count(x.codinv) As Count_codinv
            From   
            i_applnid_codinv x
            Group By x.appln_id
            Having Count(x.codinv) = 2) ac2 On ac2.appln_id = aci.appln_id
Where
    aci.codinv = 2222   
Group by
    ACI.codinv
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting.does the where clause have any matches ?

Comment: The output is only with the headers. There is no matches in this case, so that I want to show 0 and 0 for the two columns! Is this is possible?

Comment: Are you sure that your inner joins aren't causing data suppression? Change to left joins to see if you start seeing results.

Comment: I tried with LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN but nothing is happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant be done with out modifying your query..Try like below ..

**Pseudo code:**

```
select * from orderstest where empid=200 --this doesnt result any values

if @@rowcount=0
select orderid,custid from orderstest where empid=200
union all
select  top 1 null,null from orderstest
```

**Output:**

```
orderid  custid
null     null
```

Comment: Thank you for your post!

Answer (score 0):

You have no results. Check something like this...

```
 IF (SELECT COUNT(*) From    
            i_applnid_codinv aci 
            Inner Join i_applndata d On aci.appln_id = d.appln_id 
            Inner Join
                (Select x.appln_id, Count(x.codinv) As Count_codinv
                    From   
                    i_applnid_codinv x
                    Group By x.appln_id
                    Having Count(x.codinv) = 2) ac2 On ac2.appln_id = aci.appln_id
        Where
            aci.codinv = 2222   
        Group by
            ACI.codinv) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
                ACI.codinv AS codinv
                , ISNULL(COUNT(distinct ACI.appln_id), 0) AS CountInd
            From    
                i_applnid_codinv aci 
                Inner Join i_applndata d On aci.appln_id = d.appln_id 
                Inner Join
                    (Select x.appln_id, Count(x.codinv) As Count_codinv
                        From   
                        i_applnid_codinv x
                        Group By x.appln_id
                        Having Count(x.codinv) = 2) ac2 On ac2.appln_id = aci.appln_id
            Where
                aci.codinv = 2222   
            Group by
                ACI.codinv
    END
    ELSE SELECT 0,0
```

Comment: Thank you for your post!